# Proper Development Environment For React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to write an application targeted at both iOS and Android. Is it possible to develop a React Native app on Windows using a network connected Mac? For example, using Visual Studio Code on Windows and debugging on a network connected Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Atom and IDE to make react-native app.

To test on iOS, maybe you could use [this](http://www.xpadian.com/) but the best would be to have a iPhone with you, to install your app and use `Code Push` to auto update the app on your phone. The other solution would be to install an macOS Emulator on your computer.